# Can't get iOS to show alerts or notifications for app in development

Tags: xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

Platform
iOS 16 and 17

Hardware and Software Configuration
iPhone iOS 15, 16, 17
Xamarin app, developed with latest Visual Studio and paired to Mac for build using Xcode 14.3. Notifications are sent from our server to Google Firebase, and then to APNs.

Full Description
We are developing a Xamarin app for use with both Android and iOS. The app is fairly simple, consisting of a login page and a web view page. The app needs to receive push notifications from our server, and we are using Google Firebase for that purpose. The Android app is completely functional with no problems.
The iOS app is functional except that it will neither show the notifications or alerts (neither iOS alerts withUIAlertController norXamarinDisplayAlert).

The provisioning profile has APNs enabled and it is in our Entitlements.plist:

```
    <dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key> <string>production</string>
    </dict>
```

We configured Google Firebase using the APNs private key from our Apple Developer account. We have verified that notifications are being sent from our server and being received by Google Firebase for forwarding to APNs. Test notifications sent from the Google Firebase console also do not appear on the iPhone (they do appear for the Android app). We have confirmed that the iPhone app is successfully obtaining a Firebase token.

Clearly, we are missing configuration information either for our iOS build (in Info.plist, Entitlements.plist, GoogleService-Info.plist, or in the Apple provising profile), or something is missing in our Google Firebase configuration, or else there is some iPhone setting to permit notifications and alerts we are not aware of. This is what we need assistance with.

Steps to Reproduce

1. Install and run the app on an iPhone.
2. Open the app and log in. If the login is successful, the user taken to a web view page. This works fine.
3. Send a notification from our server or Google Firebase test console.
4. The notification does not appear on the iPhone. (It does work fine for the Android version of the
   app.)
5. We have looked at all known notification settings in the iOS device as per various articles
6. We have tried on multiple iOS devices with iOS 16 and 17
7. Sent notifications through Firebase to APNs to the app, and we expected them to appear on the iPhone
8. We've referred to all the answers regarding Xamarin iOS notifications already on StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you enabled Remote Notification Background Mode? In your `Info.plist` select: `Background modes` -> `Check Enabled background modes` -> `Check Remote notifications`.

Comment: Have not.  Will check that.  Our debugging shows a new twist to the issue:  The Push Notification Console (used for the test) claims we don't have an App ID with push notifications enabled, whereas we certainly do.  We double-checked this morning that both push notifications are enabled and the certificates are present.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the update, please check that. 2. Make sure you have [Register your iOS app for push notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms#register-your-ios-app-for-push-notifications).